# get coordinates with google play services vs without google play services

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-play-services

I'm trying to get the current device location but sometimes it just couldn't get it. However, i'm surprised that google maps can get it.

So i wrote a program to use LocationClient(with google-play-service) rather than LocationManager(without google-play-service).

As suspected, the LocationClient object can perform better than LocationManager. But why? Isn't both getting the result from the phone's hardware?

I've tried to decompile the google-play-service to understand further, but unfortunately some of the codes can't be decompiled.

Ultimately, im trying to create a program where it doesn't rely on google play service but still able to get the coordinates as how google maps can.

Hope you guys can help me with this. Thanks a lot!!!

Regards,
Dexter

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen Google IO last year "New Features in Android Location"?
https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325337477

the LocationClient(with google-play-service) helps you make new generation of "contextual apps". This api uses Bluetooth, accelerometer, gps, wifi and so on. Basically this api works better for tracking indoors but also works at outside. We cannot know how it works exactly cause google does not want to open source :(

Comment: Yup i did check that out. I'm thinking that probably google play service is getting the user's location periodically? That is most probable or else how are they able to locate the user so quickly and accurately? Of course with the help of sensors as well. Thoughts?

Comment: yeah but google mentioned that you can save battery by using google-play-service api. that means the play service is not tracking periodically so much. I think they use an algorithm to maintain balance if location with high accuracy has been found. Please look at find "fuesed location provider" in full-android source if you want to deeply dive to location manager. You can find this source in frameworks-level.

Comment: i read about fused location as well. Since you said that "play service is not tracking periodically so much" that means you do agree that it does periodically tracking the user right?

Answer (score 0):

Except for GPS as provider, location, in every case is not exactly dependent only on the device's hardware. Its never going to be totally independent of the device hardware but there's a difference.

While using [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html), you'd specify the PROVIDER [like GPS, Network or Passive] to obtain the [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) from.
This part would depend quite highly on the device hardware.

Till now we are talking about the [android.location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html) package for source and manager.

Now coming to the [Location APIs](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) using Google Play services SDK.
Here the important part is what they state as the source of obtaining Location:
*Fused location provider*

> The **Fused Location Provider** intelligently manages the underlying
>   location technology and gives you the best location according to your
>   needs.

So when we use [LocationClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#getLastLocation%28%29)  combined with [LocationRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html), we can specify the levels of accuracy that are required. This would then not be as highly dependent on device's hardware, but more on the accuracy level we specify.
Except for i think the case of [PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY) which would depend on the quality of GPS hardware/receiver in device.

As far as Maps is concerned, if you need the most accurate location, without Google Play Services, it can be achieved from [GPS_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#GPS_PROVIDER) only i think.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm just wondering why i can't get the lat long even with a clear sky. Maybe its a silly assumption but can i say that as long as i have a clear view to the sky, i must be able to get the lat long?

Comment: Yes, clear sky and line of sight, then lat long through GPS should be obtained quite easily

Comment: Thats why i'm confused now. I have clear sky, there are some buildings in front of me but its about 300 metres away from me. But i can't get the lat long. Basically i want to establish that the current location im at is NOT able to get the long lat but the condition seems fine to me. How can i verify that the current location is not suitable for GPS signal?

Comment: First you need to ensure that the listener is implemented correctly, check imports

Comment: also, just run google maps on your device and see if you can get the location on that, if yes then need to check your code....and if you get the location in your code after getting it on google maps then your code is fine for getting the last known location but not correctly placed for obtaining the current ones

Comment: sorry, i don't have enough reputation to upvote. Also i can't find the accept as answer button.

Comment: sorry, i should have seen the rep before saying that, its not a button, just a "tick" which appears below the vote buttons. Hey go through [SO Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) . You 'l earn the Informant badge too then :).  
Also, i said code not "placed" correctly because your code would be correct but could be calling the listeners or requesting updates with an object being null or before declaring the objects, initializing them etc, it happens a lot in such codes - related to location, bluetooth, other ones like billing, using google play services or otherwise